# $(window).load(function(){}); gives me errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(window).load(function($){});
```

Results in error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

```
$(window).load(function(){});
```

Results in: Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

What is correct way to do this? Including it in wordpress noConflict mode.

Comment: Are you positive that you are including `jQuery`, (i.e. right-click -> view source)? Your first example should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function and pass the JQuery object:

```
(function($){
   $(window).load(function(){
       // TODO
   })
})(jQuery);
```

Otherwise, try to use document.ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
// TODO
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have included jQuery correctly it IS

```
$(window).load(function () {} );
```

My guess is you did not reference jQuery though.